# Bad key CryptographicException when trying to Decrypt

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, x509certificate

I create the following files using the commands:

```
makecert -n "CN=TEST_CER" -sv "Test.pvk" -r -sky echange -pe test.cer
pvk2pfx -pvk Eltapk.pvk -spc test.cer  -pfx test.pfx -pi PVKPASS -po PFXPASS -f
```

Then i use the test.pfx in the following test application :

```
            X509Certificate2 cer2 = new X509Certificate2("test.pfx", "PFXPASS");

            RSACryptoServiceProvider PrivateKey = cer2.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
            RSACryptoServiceProvider PublicKey = cer2.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

            string test = "test123";
            byte[] testb = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test);

            testb = PublicKey.Encrypt(testb, true);
            testb = PrivateKey.Decrypt(testb, true);
            test = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(testb);
```

And I get CryptographicException: Bad Key.

I do use -sky exchange and -pe.

What I am doing wrong?

P.S. PrivateKey.Encrypt also fails with the same Exception

Comment: This code ought to work. Please look for typos: `sky echange` and I think it should be `-pvk Test.pvk`. I can't tell if they're copy/paste errors or originals. Did MakeCert respond with 'Succeeded' ?

Comment: Lol, I am ashamed it was typo and it took me over 2 hours... sky eXchange... But the makecert responded that the execution was successful. It obviously ignores any wrong flags...

Comment: That means it works now?

Comment: @HenkHolterman could you make that an answer and Blim, could you accept it so that it won't stay open?

Comment: Maybe Blim can investigate the (lack of) error messages from MakeCert a little further and post a self-answer.